# File transfer between laptops on same wifi network via browser?

Tags: wifi-transfer

Now I being using AirDroid to transfer files from my laptop to phone. Just open the app on phone, and type the address of the ip in browser on laptop and send you files.

I was wondering, if the same thing was possible between two laptops connected to the same wifi network.

I know folder and file sharing options are there, but is there a browser route too. Would love to hear from you guys, if its possible.

Comment: Yes, set up a webserver on one of the PC's, and turn on Directory browsing.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.sharedrop.io/

Just go to the above address, that's all what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If FTP is set up you can, if you navigate to  `ftp://servername` from the browser

To set up ftp , refer this serverfault.se question (for windows 7) https://serverfault.com/questions/85027/how-do-i-setup-an-ftp-server-on-windows-7

Comment: Can you expand your answer, to include the information from that link? The goal is to get as much knowledge on Super User as possible, and if Life Hacker goes down, this answer becomes useless. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the link only adds additional info. The OP didn't ask for "how" to get this done. (Or maybe I'm too lazy :D)

Comment: The answer would be much more useful with the information just on the page here, instead of having the user click through another link. That's all I'm saying.